# Listen for incoming request on port on Linux, then run command

Tags: linux, networking, port, netstat

I am after as lightweight as possible solution to listen on a port for a specific request, then run a command should the port be hit and the correct request be recedved.

Eg. Send a request to `192.168.0.10` on port `5432` with the string `my_token`. On the host (eg. `192.168.0.10`), then run a command should that port be hit and the string matched.

I was initially thinking of using `netstat` (eg. `nc -l 5000`) then running the command on change. However, ideally a string or token of sorts would be ideal alongside this or similar, but without using a full-blown webserver - essentially something that can run in the background with few resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done with `nc`. The following snippet reads lines from the port `5000` and runs `some_command` if the line is `token` or `some_other_command` if the line is `foo`. After the client disconnects, `nc` is run again.

```
while true; do
  nc -l 5000 | {
    while read line; do
      case "$line" in
        token )
          some_command;;
        foo )
          some_other_command;;
      esac
    done
  }
done
```

To talk to it, run `nc localhost 5000`, then type, e.g.:

```
foo
token
whatever
foo
```

Terminate with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. The downside is: when one client stays connected, no other can connect. To minimize such collisions you can send one command at a time and disconnect immediately:

```
echo token | nc localhost 5000
```

or (in Bash)

```
echo token > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/5000
```